# Get the value of label corresponding to the checked value of checkbox in a row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been having some issues with fetching the value of label for a corresponding `checked` value. Now i tried with `closest` attribute but it didnt work and as i dont have `tr` and cant use it as well. Issue is i am having the `checkbox` and its value inside a `li` tag. On click of `button` i call a function which needs to provide me with the `checked` values. So i am not sure how will i be able to fetch it. Below is my code and what i have tried.

```js
function test() {
  $('.chkName').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      //How do i fetch the coorresponding val?
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<li class="listRow" style=" max-width:314px; min-width:314px;">
  <label>
    <input id="id1" type="checkbox" name="" checked="checked" class="chkName">
    <label>test</label>
  </label>
</li>
<li class="listRow" style=" max-width:314px; min-width:314px;">
  <label>
    <input id="id2" type="checkbox" name="" checked="checked" class="chkName">
    <label>test1</label>
  </label>
</li>
<li class="listRow" style=" max-width:314px; min-width:314px;">
  <label>
    <input id="id3" type="checkbox" name="" class="chkName">
    <label>test2</label>
  </label>
</li>
```

Comment: The existing answers should solve your problem, but as an aside, I'd advise you avoid placing your opening {'s on the line following your code - I know this is widely practiced in other languages but you'll eventually run into issues doing it this way in JavaScript thanks to automatic semi-colon insertion: http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/08/26/javascript-semi-colon-insertion/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before we get to your question there's several issues which should be addressed. Firstly, your HTML is invalid as you have nested `<label>` elements. I'd suggets you remove the outer one and give the inner a `for` attribute to relate it to the sibling checkbox. Also, you shouldn't use inline style (or JS). The `.listRow` elements already have classes, so you can easily place the styles in a stylesheet.

As for the issue, you can use the `:checked` selector to find only the checked elements. Then, in the `each()` loop, you can use the `this` keyword to refer to the current element in the iteration. From there you can use `next()` to get the sibling label element. Try this:

```js
function test() {
  $('.chkName:checked').each(function() {
    var $label = $(this).next('label');
    console.log($label.text());
  });
}

test();
```

```css
.listRow {
  width: 314px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="listRow">
    <input id="id1" type="checkbox" name="" checked="checked" class="chkName">
    <label for="id1">test</label>
  </li>
  <li class="listRow">
    <input id="id2" type="checkbox" name="" checked="checked" class="chkName">
    <label for="id2">test1</label>
  </li>
  <li class="listRow">
    <input id="id3" type="checkbox" name="" class="chkName">
    <label for="id3">test2</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Many Thanks.. Not only for the answer but for the detailed explaintation to what the issue was and what should be the approach. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to set a value on the checkbox itself.

```
<li class="listRow" style=" max-width:314px; min-width:314px;">
        <input value="test" id="id1" type="checkbox" name="" checked="checked" class="chkName">
          <label>test</label>
</li>
<li class="listRow" style=" max-width:314px; min-width:314px;">
        <input value="test1" id="id2" type="checkbox" name="" checked="checked" class="chkName">
          <label>test1</label>
</li>
<li class="listRow" style=" max-width:314px; min-width:314px;">
        <input value="test2" id="id3" type="checkbox" name="" class="chkName">
          <label>test2</label>
</li>
```

JS:

```
 function test()
    {
         $('.chkName').each(function() 
        {
            if($(this).is(':checked'))
            {
                //How do i fetch the coorresponding val?
                console.log($(this).val())
            }
        }); 

    }
```

Otherwise, if you really want the value of the label, use "next":

```
 function test()
    {
         $('.chkName').each(function() 
        {
            if($(this).is(':checked'))
            {
                //How do i fetch the coorresponding val?
                console.log($(this).next().text())
            }
        }); 

    }
```

Comment: Firstly, always use `val()`, not `attr('value')`. Secondly, the OP looks to be trying to get the text of the label, not the value of the checkbox. I agree the title isn't clear though.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i also provided a solution for his needs, but recommend to use the value attribute